# Converting timezones in javascript resulted in very strange results, am I doing something wrong or is it a bug?

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, time, timezone

After isolating the problem in my current project .... I think something is not working currently with the Date object in javascript.

But I don't want to be arrogant because maybe I am doing something wrong, is it a bug? or am I doning something wrong?

---

I want to convert a date to diffrent time zone in javascript, I made this function:

```
function ConvertToTimeZone(date, timezone) {
   let convertedTimeString = date.toLocaleString("en-US", {hour12: false, timeZone: timezone})
   return new Date(convertedTimeString)
}
```

Then I am using it like this:

```
let testDate = new Date("Thu May 21 2020 17:04:05 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)");
let convertedDate = ConvertToTimeZone(testDate, "Europe/London");
```

Or like this:

```
let testDate = new Date("Thu May 21 2020 18:04:05 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)");
let convertedDate = ConvertToTimeZone(testDate, "UTC");
```

But something wrong is happening when I use this date:

```
let testDate = new Date("Thu May 21 2020 17:04:05 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)");
let convertedDate = ConvertToTimeZone(testDate, "UTC");
```

with that last exmaple `convertedDate` end up with `Invalid Date {}`

And when I look closely in my `ConvertToTimeZone` the result of `date.toLocaleString(...)` is `5/22/2020, 24:04:05` which looks strange because the hours of that time cannot be 24 (it should be 0)

Comment: You cannot convert time zones in the way you are trying to do here.  See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15171030/634824

Comment: **Aside note:** stop, and use libraries for doing this, for example, momentjs.  The js engines have different implementations.

Comment: Also, don't rely on the `Date` API for parsing strings.

Comment: @Ele - Preferably [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/) rather than Moment.

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint Yes, I said libraries, so the OP can opt to use what s/he thinks it's better.

Comment: Sorry, I'll be clearer:  On behalf of the Moment maintainers, of which I am one - please only use Moment for new projects. Luxon is in the Moment family, and we prefer you use it instead.  Luxon is designed for modern applications. Moment is legacy.

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint—don't you mean only use Moment for existing projects?

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint Luxon looks nice but I think I will use moment because I am using ant-design (https://ant.design/) and some of the apis there use moment as default

Comment: Your "conversion" to another timezone is fine, the issue is expecting to parse it back correctly. The output of *toLocaleString* is implementation dependent and there is no requirement for the implementation that created it to correctly parse it back to a date (mostly because users can configure the string in ways the parser has no knowledge of). So your issue is parsing, not changing timezones. :-)

Comment: In regard to the 24:00 issue, change the language tag to "en-US-u-h23" to force the [hour cycle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat) to be 23 (under certain conditions DateTimeFormat defaults to a 24 hour cycle).