# Get Epoch time value for different TimeZone

Tags: javascript, angular, date, timezone

My local time zone is IST , i tried to define timezone inside Date object like

```
const usaRegionTime = new Date(inputDate.toString()).toLocaleString(
        'en-US',
        {
          timeZone: 'America/New_York',
        }
      );
      const estDate = new Date(usaRegionTime);
console.log(estDate.getTime());// Uses IST(local time Zone) instead of EST(Specifed time zone)
```

**Example**:

> My IST time is 7:15 PM and i use the Date object with EST timeZone i get correct EST as 9:45 AM but when i try est.getTime() UTC is calculated as 7:15 pm instead of 1:45 pm . Its taking 9:45 am as IST(Local time Zone) before converting to UTC(Epoch).

**Problem is its Taking Browser local timeZone(IST) instead of TimeZone(EST)** i gave as param to Date object to get Epoch value . Is there a way to override the **Local time Zone** with **Specified TimeZone** while getting Epoch value.

Comment: What you're trying to do is flawed, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15171030/257182). This is likely a duplicate of [Converting timezones in javascript resulted in very strange results, am I doing something wrong or is it a bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61901653/converting-timezones-in-javascript-resulted-in-very-strange-results-am-i-doing)

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to override the Local time Zone with Specified TimeZone while getting Epoch value.

No. You can generate a timestamp for any supported [IANA representative location](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones), but you can't "set a timezone" for the Date instance itself.

ECMAScript Date objects are just a time value that is an offset in milliseconds from 1 Jan 1970 UTC. They have no timezone and can only work in either the local timezone or UTC, that's it. When parsing a timestamp for a particular timezone, the result is a UTC time value. That is the only thing the Date instance remembers so it doesn't matter how you generate a Date, the time value is always effectively UTC.

The plain *get* and *set* methods like *getYear*, *getMintues*, etc. and the *toString* methods use the UTC time value and host settings to generate local date and time values. The UTC *get* and *set* methods like *getUTCYear*, *getUTCMintues*, etc. and *toISOString*, *toUTCString* etc.  return UTC values. So you can work in either local or UTC, working in some other timezone or location requires you to do the work (which is quite complex and likely a library is a better option).

You can get a timestamp for any supported IANA representative location using *toLocaleString* with the *timeZone* option, however that only affects the generated string, it doesn't change the underlying UTC time value.

You can't set a timezone or location for a Date object as it doesn't have any property on which to set it, it's just a (UTC) time value, that's it.

Also, the built–in parser is not required to parse the output from *toLocaleString*, primarily because the user can configure the output to a huge number of different formats that may not include any date or time values (e.g. you can get just the timezone or offset). So depending on parsing such values is fundamentally flawed.

Comment: Thanks Rob its clear now.... As you mentioned how can I  get the offset for the timezone I set as option to date?

Comment: @Mithunabisheg—see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61364310/257182).

Answer (score 0):

```
var date= new Date().valueOf(); //gives UTC timestamp in millisecond
const usaRegionTime = new Date(date).toLocaleString(
        'en-US',
        {
          timeZone: 'America/New_York',
        }
      );
  const estDate = new Date(usaRegionTime).toString();
console.log(estDate);
```

Comment: now if we use getTime method of estDate  , It will take local timezone for Epoch conversion but i want to override the local time zone will epoch conversion

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36206260/how-to-set-date-always-to-eastern-time-regardless-of-users-time-zone

Comment: Thanks but this does not take in daylight saving into account and so offset cannot be constant value it changes in a cycle

Comment: This only works if the host offset settings match the desired location.